# Changing content dynamically in WPF window from UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two `UserControls`, for example, `FirstUserControl` and `SecondUserControl`. In first I set the `FirstUserControl` in MainWindow with help `<ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" />`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.contentControl.Content = new LoginControl();
}
```

But, when user press the button, what located in the FirstUserControl `ContentControl` in MainWindow must change to SecondUserControl. But it doesn't happen. ContentControl remains FirstUserControl. What could be the problem - I don't know.

This code is from FirstUserControl:

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(new CheckInCheckOutControl());
}
```

And it's consructor from MainWindow, whish is responsible for shanging ContentControl:

```
public MainWindow(ContentControl contentControl)
{
    this.contentControl.Content = contentControl;
}
```

And I have tried also to carry out changes to a separate method in the MainWindow - but it didn't help.

Comment: `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(new CheckInCheckOutControl());` creates a new instance of MainWindow. don't do that. MainWindow owns FirstUserControl and SecondUserControl, threfore it is MainWindow who should change them, not FirstUserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(new CheckInCheckOutControl());` creates a new instance of MainWindow, instead of using already open MainWindow. don't do that.

MainWindow owns FirstUserControl and SecondUserControl, therefore it is MainWindow who should change them, not FirstUserControl.

create an event in FirstUserControl

```
public event EventHandler LoginClick;

private void loginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (LoginClick != null) LoginClick(this, e);
}
```

in MainWindow, which owns FirstUserControl instance, subscribe to that event and change content:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var loginControl = new LoginControl();

    loginControl.LoginClick += (senser, e) =>
    {
         this.contentControl.Content = new CheckInCheckOutControl();
    }

    this.contentControl.Content = loginControl;
}
```

Comment: About creating a new instance of MainWindow you are right. But, no, your code doesn't help.

Comment: @HannaBilous, did you tried to set a breakpoint on this line `this.contentControl.Content = ...`?

Comment: I had set a breakpoint and found out that `if (LoginClick != null) LoginClick(this, e);` returns the value `false`. `LoginClick` is `null`

Comment: do you have subscription `LoginClick +=` anythere?

Comment: No, I think that "LoginClick" must be the value of some property. But I don't know what property. I was finding on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button_events(v=vs.110).aspx), but have not yet found it.

Comment: `LoginClick` is an event, and each instance of FirstUserControl has that event. MainWindow contains FirstUserControl, so can subscribe. please show how FirstUserControl is used in mainwindow

Comment: `LoginControl loginControl = new LoginControl();
   loginControl.LoginClick += (senser, e) =>
   {
    this.contentControl.Content = new CheckInCheckOutControl();
   }; `

It is in `public MainWindow()`